# how to add a widget to the final view at runtime in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I'm looking for a way to add a widget to the final view without modifiying View or layout file.
imagine you are creating a composer package which contains a Bootstrap class(a class which implements yii\base\BootstrapInterface ) and a simple widget which is responsible to display a simple timer .
you want to add this widget to all Views in all web responses..how you do this?
I don't like to touch my view files or layout files , I'm just tryng to create a package which must do this by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using yii2 here, and you must not touch the layout and view files.

You can

**1. Use the afterRender Function**

For this you will need to override the View class, add your own `afterRender`   function that processes the page and adds your widget(s) as per your own defined rules. 
Then you can call

```
 $this->view->on('afterRender', ...);
```

to do whatever you want on after render.

Since the controller calls the default view class, you will also need to override the yii\web\controller class and change the view class used.

**2. Use Javascript to get widget and display to user**

Add a javascript that will append the widget element at the correct place, fetched using ajax from a separate independent (partial) view file .

**3.In case if developing an extension**

You can trigger a function on the view body begin or end in your bootstrap function

```
$app->on(Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST, function () use ($app) {
        $app->getView()->on(View::EVENT_END_PAGE, [$this, 'renderWidget']);
    });
```

And add a renderWidget function similar to this :

```
    public function renderWidget($event){
        $view = $event->sender;
        echo "extra html at end of page";
    }
```

Comment: thanks for details and nice answer but the problem is I'm creating a package and all I have is a Bootstrap class which will be called in bootstrap stage of each web request.    


I don't have access to Config file of the project to change the View class .
and also I can't set the View using $app->view = new MyOwnView(); in my bootstrap because $app->view is a read-only property .
when the framework execute the bootstrap function of my Bootstrap class the view already set and I can't change it .     
how can I override the View class in my bootstrap function ?

Comment: I have added another option to cover your requirement.